# Animated class on addClass not working

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following CSS for an effect class:

```
@keyframes shake {
    10%, 90% {
        transform: translate3d(-1px, 0, 0);
    }

    20%, 80% {
        transform: translate3d(2px, 0, 0);
    }

    30%, 50%, 70% {
        transform: translate3d(-4px, 0, 0);
    }

    40%, 60% {
        transform: translate3d(4px, 0, 0);
    }
}
.effect {
    animation: shake 1s cubic-bezier(.36,.07,.19,.97) both;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    perspective: 1000px;
}
```

Using the the `jquery.appear` functionality, I add the class `.effect` when a button appears in the viewport. The class is indeed added to the button, but the shake is not done as intended. So my guess is you cannot add a class like I am doing now to show the user the effect. Or because it's once...

Below the JS code:

```
$('.parent .link').appear();
$('.parent .link').on('appear', function(event, $elements) {
    $(this).addClass('effect');
});
```

Which correctly adds the class to below element:

```
<a class="link effect" href="/new-page">
    <span>Click me</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting the code you provided into a pen and simply adding a display property to either the .link or .effect class allows the transform property to move the element in my case.

```
.link {
  display:inline-block;
 }
```

if this solution doesn't work then if you could provide an example it would make it considerably easier to fix.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the code of the JS a bit by first removing the element and then placing it back with the effect. This makes the effect from CSS start from beginning:

```
$('.parent .link').appear();
$('.parent .link').on('appear', function(event, $elements) {
    $(this).addClass('effect');
    var id = $(this).closest(".parent").attr('id');
    var $button = $(this).detach();
    $button.appendTo(("#"+id+" .parent"));
});
```